# How to extract attribute inside class (?) with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, attributes

I've been trying all day to get the value inside **'data-tippy-content'**  from:

```
<span class="opacity-70">
  <span class="icon-small mr-1" data-tippy-content="Niacinamide"><img loading="lazy" src="https://skinsort.com/assets/icons/thumbnail/niacinamide-def098d8bdadc1b0e2f848d8e77e6ca5d744099553ff816b09d4f3521abe0bc0.png"></span>
  <span class="icon-small mr-1" data-tippy-content="Good for Oily Skin"><img loading="lazy" src="https://skinsort.com/assets/icons/thumbnail/best_oil-3587634ebcb8ef7c01c9959a4cbcbc2d85f2990a9216d24ec1081f1a931c4264.png"></span>
  <span class="icon-small mr-1" data-tippy-content="Helps reduce Skin Redness"><img loading="lazy" src="https://skinsort.com/assets/icons/thumbnail/best_redness-8684f0660c6620202a754fd9bd20a0378f89d43fe2cb0fdc19a4b26af1f0b9b6.png"></span><span class="icon-small mr-1" data-tippy-content="Helps fight Acne"><img loading="lazy" src="https://skinsort.com/assets/icons/thumbnail/best_acne-82d0b5bc5978478dd67def5e721767e35db9523db64e7756343c95bfb99f842f.png"></span>
  <span class="icon-small mr-1" data-tippy-content="Helps brighten skin"><img loading="lazy" src="https://skinsort.com/assets/icons/thumbnail/best_brightening-ea550c7d84d6517a76f19bab645a747913a49fe0a565f177cfa1b73f20a89d21.png"></span>
</span>
```

I've tried a lot of things but still :")

I have the following code (THe problem is in the **'effect'**):

```
items = soup.findAll('div', 'relative flex flex-col min-w-0 rounded-2xl break-words border-2 border-blue-gray-100 h-full lg:h-72')
ef_list = []
for i in items:
    name = i.find('h4', 'mb-1 leading-tight text-blue-gray-700 group-hover:underline font-header text-xl font-bold hover:underline whitespace-normal overflow-hidden').text.strip()
    function  = i.find('p', 'mb-0 text-sm').text.strip()
    effect = i.find('span', 'opacity-70').find('span')['data-tippy-content']
    print(effect)
    data.append([name, function,effect])
```

I expect the output to be something like:

```
"Niacinamide, Good for Oily Skin, Helps reduce Skin Redness, Helps brighten skin"
```

but instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Scrape\scrape.py", line 36, in <module>
    print(effect['data-tippy-content'])
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1519, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'data-tippy-content'
```

I've no idea how to get those "data-tippy-content" (I'm new at this)

here is the css for the inspect:
[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BIao.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value that you want to pull in attribute that's `data-tippy-content`
.So simply you can call `get('data-tippy-content)` to get desired data

```
html = '''
<span class="opacity-70">
  <span class="icon-small mr-1" data-tippy-content="Niacinamide"><img loading="lazy" src="https://skinsort.com/assets/icons/thumbnail/niacinamide-def098d8bdadc1b0e2f848d8e77e6ca5d744099553ff816b09d4f3521abe0bc0.png"></span>
  <span class="icon-small mr-1" data-tippy-content="Good for Oily Skin"><img loading="lazy" src="https://skinsort.com/assets/icons/thumbnail/best_oil-3587634ebcb8ef7c01c9959a4cbcbc2d85f2990a9216d24ec1081f1a931c4264.png"></span>
  <span class="icon-small mr-1" data-tippy-content="Helps reduce Skin Redness"><img loading="lazy" src="https://skinsort.com/assets/icons/thumbnail/best_redness-8684f0660c6620202a754fd9bd20a0378f89d43fe2cb0fdc19a4b26af1f0b9b6.png"></span><span class="icon-small mr-1" data-tippy-content="Helps fight Acne"><img loading="lazy" src="https://skinsort.com/assets/icons/thumbnail/best_acne-82d0b5bc5978478dd67def5e721767e35db9523db64e7756343c95bfb99f842f.png"></span>
  <span class="icon-small mr-1" data-tippy-content="Helps brighten skin"><img loading="lazy" src="https://skinsort.com/assets/icons/thumbnail/best_brightening-ea550c7d84d6517a76f19bab645a747913a49fe0a565f177cfa1b73f20a89d21.png"></span>
</span>

'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

txt=[x.get('data-tippy-content') for x in soup.select('.opacity-70 span')]
print(txt)
```

**Output:**

```
['Niacinamide', 'Good for Oily Skin', 'Helps reduce Skin Redness', 'Helps fight Acne', 'Helps 
brighten skin']
```

Comment: Thanku so much,  i've tried your code, but it doesn't scrape well :(.

the scrape result from your code is scraping all the 'data-tippy-content' value from the 
whole web, not just that one block.

is there any way to just scape per block instead of the whole html ?

Comment: Nevermind I got it, I misstype the 'soup' where it should be 'i' for my case Thanku somuchh!